# coldfusion web-inf\web.xml purpose

Tags: coldfusion, web.xml

Im looking at using New Relic for monitoring our coldfusion sites. however it uses the web application display name defined in web.xml to define applications in its admin.

As far as I can work out coldfusion only have the one web.xml file in:
...\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\WEB-INF\web.xml

What is the purpose of this file? and can elements of it be overwritten on a site by site basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like New Relic is a tool for monitoring Java (and other) apps. ColdFusion is a Java application. And the way you have it installed (standard) it is a single application with a single web.xml. Regardless of how many ColdFusion sites (apps) you run on it, it is still a single web application.

If you have CF Enterprise you can set up a multi-server install where you can deploy each of your sites as a separate Java app, but the way you have it set up now, you'll probably only be able to monitor CF as a whole vs each individual site.